# Rails project setup problems on VScode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I setup the Rails project on VScode but it does not produce the expected outcome. It just profile 6 single files and does not have any folders.

I followed all the step in: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html and also install extension for Ruby and Rails on VScode but cannot set the expected Rails setup

Comment: sorry but to help you we need more information:  
 - are you developing on Windows or Linux  
- when using the tutorial, which steps succeded  
- what is your "expected outcome"

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.